# Django channels self.send() from custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-channels

Is it possible to `self.send()` from custom function inside consumer.py?

I have a roulette game which runs inside a loop after every 30 seconds. Inside that loop I call a function to save the winning game details and update the user model with their winnings. I would like to also send that to the front end view so the user does not need to refresh the page to update their balance.

The problem currently is that the way I thought to do it is not working as the `self.send()` inside my custom `save_roll()` function is not working.

How can something like this be achieved?

```
consumers.py

@database_sync_to_async
def save_roll(self, result, roll_color, round_number):
    winners = Bets.objects.filter(round_number=round_number, bet_choice=roll_color)
    multiplier = 0

    if roll_color == 'blue' or roll_color == 'red':
        multiplier = 2
    elif roll_color == 'green':
        multiplier = 14

    for winner in winners:
        
        winnerId = winner.id
        winnerBet = winner.bet_value
        userObj = CustomUser.objects.filter(id=winnerId)[0]
        newBalance = userObj.user_coins + (winnerBet * multiplier)
        
        CustomUser.objects.filter(id=winnerId).update(user_coins=newBalance)

        self.send(text_data = json.dumps({
            'balance': newBalance
        }))

    Roulette.objects.create(win = result, roll_color = roll_color, round_number = round_number, is_over = True)

class RouletteGame(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):

    async def connect(self):
        self.connected = True
        await self.accept()

        while self.connected:
            await asyncio.sleep(30)

            server_seed = get_random_string(length=64)
            public_seed = random.randint(0, 999999)
            round = await get_round() + 1
            print(round)

            hash = pbkdf2_hmac('sha256', bytes(server_seed, 'utf-8'), bytes(public_seed), round)

            result = int(hash[0:8].hex(), 16) % 15

            roll_color = ''

            if result == 0:
                roll_color = 'green'
            elif result >= 1 and result <= 7:
                roll_color = 'blue'
            elif result >= 8 and result <= 14:
                roll_color = 'red'

            await save_roll(self, result, roll_color, round)

            await self.send(text_data = json.dumps({
                'round_result': result
            }))     

    async def disconnect(self):
        self.connected = False
```